# Tensorflow exploding gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have a CNN architecture to output the coordinates of a box around an object:

[image: CNN Architecture]

However if I implement it in tf, the loss becomes nan even after one epoch. I tried gradient clipping and batch normalization, but neither works. I suspect that something is wrong with my loss, here is the corresponding code:

```
...
output = tf.layers.dense(dense, 4, name="output")

# Loss
error = output-y
error_sq = tf.square(error)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(error_sq, axis=-1)

# Training operation
optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001, momentum=0.9, decay=0.0, epsilon=1e-08)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

I implemented the same architecture with keras and it works fine:

```
...
model.add(Dense(4))

# Optimizer
optimizer = RMSprop(lr=0.001, rho=0.9, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)

# Compile
model.compile(optimizer = optimizer , loss = "mean_squared_error", metrics=["mean_squared_error"])
```

I can not see where the two differ..

Note 1:
I also get nan's if I drop the axis=-1 argument, however I included it since the keras mean is computed with the same argument.

Note 2:
Even if I train just a dense layer on the input the keras model slowly converges while the tensorflow model does not.

Comment: As a side note, you can use `tf.losses.mean_squared_error` to get the mean squared error in tensorflow.

Comment: What happens if you define the network with Keras and optimize it with native tensorflow code like in your first snippet? What is the shape of `error`?

Comment: @BiBi If i use plain tf to optimize the keras model I have the same issue. The shape of the error is (25,4), where 25 is my batch size, the other dimension has the coordinates of the localization box.

Comment: If your batch dimension is the 0th axis, I guess you should reduce along this axis with `loss = tf.reduce_mean(error_sq, axis=0)` instead of `axis=-1`, but that should be the the problem.

Comment: Yes, changing the axis just changes the shape of the nan-array I get ;) I chose axis=-1 because to my understanding keras uses it (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/losses.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The catch may be because of the line, `error = output-y`. Because `output` is the Logits or the Probability of Prediction of each class.

If we print it, it will be as shown below:

```
output/logits =  [[-4.55290842e+00  9.54713643e-01  2.04970908e+00 ...  1.06385863e+00
  -1.76558220e+00  5.84793314e-02]
 [ 1.42444344e+01 -3.09316659e+00  4.31246233e+00 ... -1.64039159e+00
  -4.75767326e+00  2.69032687e-01]
 [-3.66746974e+00 -1.05631983e+00  1.63249350e+00 ...  2.34054995e+00
  -2.86306214e+00 -1.29766455e-02]
 ...
 [ 1.92035064e-01  2.18118310e+00  1.05751991e+01 ... -3.32132912e+00
   2.23277748e-01 -4.14045334e+00]
 [-3.95318937e+00  7.54375601e+00  5.60657620e-01 ...  3.35071832e-02
   2.31437039e+00 -3.36187315e+00]
 [-4.37104368e+00  4.23799706e+00  1.20920219e+01 ... -1.18962801e+00
   2.23617482e+00 -3.06528354e+00]]
```

Hence the steps `error = output-y`, `error_sq = tf.square(error)` and 
`loss = tf.reduce_mean(error_sq, axis=-1)` might be resulting in NaN.

Below code should resolve your issue:

```
l1 = tf.layers.dense(normed_train_data, 64, activation='relu')
l2 = tf.layers.dense(l1, 64, activation='relu')
l3 = tf.layers.dense(l2, 4, name="output")

mse = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y, logits=l3)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(mse, name="loss")

optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001, momentum=0.9, decay=0.0, epsilon=1e-08)
training_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, y, 1)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct, tf.float32))
```